# DVI 'Y' spliter and 2 monitors

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, window

I have set up 2 monitors on my PC (Window Vista Home Edition) and connected them with a 'Y' splitter DVI cable to extend my desktop. The problem is it won't extend. All it does is mirroring the desktop. Please let me know how to extend. I have tried several times by going through the settings but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "Y" splitter will only ever duplicate the signal - thus the mirroring. You must have a graphics card capable of dual monitors. Some specialist cards have one socket but have a custom cable to connect multiple monitors.

Does your motherboard have two DVI sockets, or a DVI and a VGA? If it had either then you should be able to use two monitors independently. If you only have one DVI or VGA then you will only ever get one monitor output.

Comment: @Sickest, read the answer again.  He didn't ask a question of the OP.  His second paragraph is a conditional expression.  Read it as: **if** spare video port **then** use spare port **else** SOL.